# How to wait for thread pool to finish all tasks?

Tags: java

I am creating a thread pool executor and want it to finish all tasks before going forward:
for Example:

```
ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

while(...) {

    taskExecutor.execute(new MyTask());
    taskExecutor.execute(new MyTask());
    taskExecutor.execute(new MyTask());

}

//...wait for completion somehow
```

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple ways to do so:

but the popular one is using threadpool.shutdown():

```
public void awaitTerminationAfterShutdown(ExecutorService threadPool) {
    threadPool.shutdown();
    try {
        if (!threadPool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            threadPool.shutdownNow();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        threadPool.shutdownNow();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Different from the answer written, in scenarios the person will not usually know when the job finishes. As a rule of thumb, a more better approach is to have a callback from the running task.

You can do so like the following:

```
class MyTask implements Callable {...}//and do your task inside the "call" method
```

And then :

```
List<MyTask> allMyTasks // have all your tasks piled up 
List<Future<TaskOutPut>> futures = taskExecutor.invokeAll(allMyTasks);

List<TaskOutPut> output = futures.map(future->future.get()).collect(Collectors.toList()); //this will make sure every future is completed
```